# C++ iterators on string point to null characters when using string.replace on string that results in a string longer than 22

Tags: c++, string, iterator

The code works fine and outputs as normal *as long as I don't increase the size of this string*. Adding a single character more at declaration of string (t1) or in the replacement statement breaks the iterators.

My original code has a bunch of printing statements for outputting to a log file, and some other futzing around, <strike>but I see little point to including all clutter since it works just fine... provided I don't add another character.</strike>. This code is now included at the bottom.

Code (bare bones):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::string t1 = "12345abcd";
    std::string::iterator itB = t1.begin() + 3;
    std::string::iterator itE = t1.end() - 4;
    // iterator std::distance shows 2

    // Problem line
    t1.replace(t1.begin() + 5, t1.begin() + 7, "%abcdefghijklm%");
}
```

Again, this breaks if one more character is added to either t1 (e.g. 12345abcde") or to the replacement string argument (e.g. "%abcdefghijklmn%"). Besides C++ refusing to continue in my original code (and outputting null characters to the log text file before stopping), I went through with the VSCode debugger to see that the null characters (this is on the original, messier code, but it still does the same thing on the short code above).

Debugger snapshots:

[image: Fine]

[image: Not fine]

I've tried changing the amount of offsets from the beginning and end (or just using straight begin or end), shortening one string argument then making the other bigger. Still seems to break at string size of 22 and output as expected in the other cases I've tried with iterators that are in-range for the string. The replacement string is surrounded by %

Output log text file from original code with output statements:

```
string size, string
9
12345abcd
print from iterator beg+3, iterator end-4 from end
45abcd
abcd
iterator distance
2
print from iterator beg+3 to iterator end-4
45

new string (replace index 0 to 2-noninclusive), stringsize, iterator distance
%abcdefghijklm%345abcd
22
2

print from iterator beg+3 to iterator end-4
cd

print from iterator beg+3
cdefghijklm%345abcd
print from iterator end-4
efghijklm%345abcd

print string, replace (remove) using iterators
%abcdefghijklm%345abcd
%abefghijklm%345abcd
print from iterator beg+3 to iterator end-4
ef
```

Successful output as expected.

Log when it breaks:

```
string size, string
9
12345abcd
print from iterator beg+3, iterator end-4 from end
45abcd
abcd
iterator distance
2
print from iterator beg+3 to iterator end-4
45

new string (replace index 0 to 2-noninclusive), stringsize, iterator distance
%abcdefghijklmn%345abcd
23
2

print from iterator beg+3 to iterator end-4
//NOTE: VSCode indicates 2 null characters here

print from iterator beg+3
```

and it stops further operations at this point.

To be clear, I'm just experimenting with iterators to learn and not trying to accomplish any task other than understand what's going on.

Using VSCode on macOS 11.7

Working versions of the original code that produced the text output is below. Broken version just added an

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

void print(auto value)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

void print(std::string &s, std::string::iterator itr)
{
    while (itr != s.end())
    {
        std::cout << *itr;
        itr++;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void print(std::string::iterator itr1, std::string::iterator itr2)
{
    while (itr1 != itr2)
    {
        std::cout << *itr1;
        itr1++;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    freopen("myOutput.txt", "w", stdout);

    std::string t1 = "12345abcd";
    std::string::iterator itB = t1.begin() + 3;
    std::string::iterator itE = t1.end() - 4;
    print("string size, string");
    print(t1.size());
    print(t1);

    print("print from iterator beg+3, iterator end-4 from end");
    print(t1, itB);
    print(t1, itE);
    print("iterator distance");
    print(std::distance(itB, itE));
    
    print("print from iterator beg+3 to iterator end-4");
    print(itB, itE);
    print("");

    print("new string (replace index 0 to 2-noninclusive), stringsize, iterator distance");
    std::cout << t1.replace(t1.begin() + 0, t1.begin() + 2, "%abcdefghijklm%") << std::endl;
    print(t1.size());
    //interesting note: after string size passes 22, either from this replacement, or from making it longer in initial declaration, it breaks the iterators
    print(std::distance(itB, itE));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    print("print from iterator beg+3 to iterator end-4");
    print(itB, itE);
    print("");
    print("print from iterator beg+3");
    print(t1, itB);
    print("print from iterator end-4");
    print(t1, itE);

    print("");
    print("print string, replace (remove) using iterators");
    print(t1);
    std::cout << t1.replace(itB, itE, "") << std::endl;

    print("print from iterator beg+3 to iterator end-4");
    print(itB, itE);
    
    
}
```

Comment: **std::distance shows 3** This is wrong in the shown code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: When you cause a string to get longer than its `capacity()` it has to reallocate more storage, which involves copying the old string data and then releasing the old storage. When a string grows this way, all iterators to it are invalidated, along with any pointer or reference to the old data.

Comment: @273K My mistake; that was from the code with an extra character in t1. This should now run as is and the comment correct.

Comment: Please post the actual code you are running as text, not images.

Comment: The shown code is correct. François Andrieux gave you answer to your not shown code.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux this answered the question, thank you.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It is posted as text. The images are screenshots from a GUI debugger.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: The code posted as text is not the actual code being run.  The problem turned out to be in the "bunch of printing statements for outputting to a log file, and some other futzing around" which OP trimmed away when posting the question.

Comment: @BenVoigt that is not correct. The problem was, indeed, in the code as given here. I redid the screenshots of the debugger GUI using the code as provided to show the same result, so the original post should now reflect that. I confirmed Francois' answer with t1="12345abcd" since t1.capacity() returned 22. Exactly the size where it broke.

Comment: @Morgan: The problem is in "use of `itB` and `itE` after the `replace`", which is not part of the code given here.  The code you posted in the question doesn't use `itB` or `itE` at all, either before the replace (when it is safe) or after (when it is verboten)

Comment: : Important note -- @FrançoisAndrieux is correct that when reallocation occurs, all iterators are invalidated, but this is not the only condition for invalidation.  Even in the absence of reallocation, iterators after the first argument of `replace` are invalidated.

Comment: @BenVoigt original code added. Reasoning: this was the minimum code to cause the root issue as indicated by the debugger (see updated screenshots). Uses of `itB` and `itE` prior to the breakpoint worked as intended, but too numerous to include. I understand your criticism (and considered it myself), but still concluded that the tradeoff for interpretability was worth it, as under-the-hood is the goal. That said, I invite you to review the full code, since the iterators appear to have worked as I intended, though your experience indicates they should not have after that replace statement.

Comment: One of the possible behaviors of Undefined Behavior is that it does what you expected.  But it is not specified to do so, and can surprise you at any time.

Comment: @BenVoigt that's a very good point. To be clear, earlier when you said, "iterators after," do you mean iterators for that string are invalidated after the operation, or that iterators pointing to locations that are at or past the location of the replacement should be considered invalidated? That is, assuming the string memory location doesn't change (e.g. no size/cap increase caused), iterators starting at locations preceding the target of changes like `replace` should retain integrity?

Comment: @Morgan: I meant "after" in element order, not in time.  For `std::vector` it's explicitly stated: https://eel.is/c++draft/vector#modifiers-2 and https://eel.is/c++draft/vector#modifiers-3 but for `std::string` it's a much broader statement: https://eel.is/c++draft/string.require#4   This is probably because `std::string` can use the small string optimization, causing the content address to change even for decrease in size.

Comment: @BenVoigt understood, thank you for taking the time to explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @FrançoisAndrieux for identifying the root cause as memory allocation for the string.

Demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string t1 = "12345abcd";
    std::string::iterator itB = t1.begin() + 3;
    std::string::iterator itE = t1.end() - 4;
    // iterator std::distance shows 2

    std::cout << "t1 before replacement" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "t1 capacity: " << t1.capacity() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "t1 size: " << t1.size() << std::endl;

    // Problem line
    t1.replace(t1.begin() + 5, t1.begin() + 7, "%abcdefghijklm%");

    std::cout << "t1 after replacement (size increases)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "t1 capacity: " << t1.capacity() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "t1 size: " << t1.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Produces output

```
t1 before replacement
t1 capacity: 22
t1 size: 9
t1 after replacement (size increases)
t1 capacity: 22
t1 size: 22
```

While the additional character (as in the edited post, it is an additional 'n' in the replacement string argument), as below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string t1 = "12345abcd";
    std::string::iterator itB = t1.begin() + 3;
    std::string::iterator itE = t1.end() - 4;
    // iterator std::distance shows 2

    std::cout << "t1 before replacement" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "t1 capacity: " << t1.capacity() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "t1 size: " << t1.size() << std::endl;

    // Problem line 
    t1.replace(t1.begin() + 5, t1.begin() + 7, "%abcdefghijklmn%");

    std::cout << "t1 after replacement (size increases)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "t1 capacity: " << t1.capacity() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "t1 size: " << t1.size() << std::endl;
}
```

led to output

```
t1 before replacement
t1 capacity: 22
t1 size: 9
t1 after replacement (size increases)
t1 capacity: 47
t1 size: 23
```

Borking the iterators.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the original string has its data placed on the stack. After the `replace`, the data is placed on the heap.

I'm a bit of a c++ novice, so I wrote a test program (below):

Here is the program output:

```
dumpstr: SYMBOL t1/orig
dumpstr: STRING '12345abcde'
dumpstr: SIZE 10
dumpstr: CAP 15
dumpstr: PTR 0x7ffeef8a2770
dumpiter: itB '4'
0x7ffeef8a2773
dumpiter: itE 'b'
0x7ffeef8a2776

dumpstr: SYMBOL t1/post
dumpstr: STRING '12345%abcdefghijklmn%cde'
dumpstr: SIZE 24
dumpstr: CAP 30
dumpstr: PTR 0xca8e80
dumpiter: itB '^@'
0x7ffeef8a2773
dumpiter: itE '^@'
0x7ffeef8a2776
```

Note the change in the `PTR` value (which is where the string data resides):

- 0x7ffeef8a2770 [stack]
- 0xca8e80 [heap]

Also, note that the iterators still point to the stack even after the `replace`.

---

Here is the program. Please excuse the use of `printf` as I couldn't figure out the correct stream equivalent:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

#if MODE == 0
#define ORIG    "12345abcd"
#define NEWS    "%abcdefghijklm%"
#else
#define ORIG    "12345abcde"
#define NEWS    "%abcdefghijklmn%"
#endif

void
dumpiter(const std::string::iterator& iter,const char *tag)
{

    std::cout << "dumpiter: " << tag << " '" << *iter << "'\n";
    printf("%p\n",&(*iter));
}

void
dumpstr(const std::string& str,const char *tag)
{

    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "dumpstr: SYMBOL " << tag << "\n";
    std::cout << "dumpstr: STRING '" << str << "'\n";
    std::cout << "dumpstr: SIZE " << str.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "dumpstr: CAP " << str.capacity() << "\n";
    printf("dumpstr: PTR %p\n",str.c_str());
#if 0
    dumpiter(str.cbegin(),"beg");
    dumpiter(str.cend(),"end");
#endif
}

int
main()
{
    std::string t1 = ORIG;
    std::string::iterator itB = t1.begin() + 3;
    std::string::iterator itE = t1.end() - 4;
    // iterator std::distance shows 2

    dumpstr(t1,"t1/orig");
    dumpiter(itB,"itB");
    dumpiter(itE,"itE");

    // Problem line
#if 1
    t1.replace(t1.begin() + 5, t1.begin() + 7, NEWS);
    dumpstr(t1,"t1/post");
    dumpiter(itB,"itB");
    dumpiter(itE,"itE");
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm still a comp sci student, so that's much appreciated insight on stack vs heap usage. I don't understand the syntax (in particular how MODE works), but when I run this on my machine I get different results--mine is macOS; is yours on Windows? Editing it to exceed the 22 cap (it won't do it, otherwise) does cause a PTR change, but it appears to still be a stack address: 

(original)

`dumpstr: PTR 0x7ffee7a8f501`

(post) 

`dumpstr: SYMBOL t1/post`

`dumpstr: STRING '12345%abcdeffffghijklm%cd'`

`dumpstr: SIZE 25`

`dumpstr: CAP 47`

`dumpstr: PTR 0x7ff9e2c05a40`